# Scrapy: Create Project returning error

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm learning `scrapy` to create a crawler that could crawl website and get back the results, however on creating a new project, it is returning an error.
I tried creating a folder manually, but again it returned an error.
Any idea how to resolve this.

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

`import scrapy
 scrapy startproject stack`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying the command `scrapy startproject stack` inside python interactive shell.
Run the same command directly on bash shell, and not inside python shell.
And you don't need `import scrapy` command  to create a scrapy project.

Comment: thanks Chandra for your comment. May I know where would this stack project be created? Although I ran this command successfully, but I'm not able to see any folder being created.

Comment: Scrapy tutorial covers [that part creating a project](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#creating-a-project). You should have the folder structure from that page relative to where you launched `scrapy startproject yourprojectname`. Python programming, `import scrapy`, creating spider classes etc. is to be done after that, inside `yourprojectname/spiders/somespider.py` python modules.